# __init__.py needed for imports to work in Pytest. But using Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have read that after Python 3.3, `__init__.py` is not required anymore, So I am not understanding why I need to add it (`__init__.py`) for my pytests to work.

Directory structure:

```
|- root/
   |- foo/
       |- bar.py
   |- tests/
       |- test_bar.py
```

In **/foo/bar.py** I have the following code

```
def five():
    return 5
```

In **test_bar.py** I have the following code

```
from foo import bar

test_bar():
    assert bar.five() == 5
```

I run the tests from /root like this:

```
/root$ pytest
```

If I place a `__init__.py` file in `/tests`, the test passes. Without it, I get the following error:

```
============ test session starts ============
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/my_user/my_folder/root
collected 0 items / 1 error     
______________ ERROR collecting tests/test_sorting.py ______________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/my_user/my_folder/root/tests/test_bar.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_bar.py:1: in <module>
    from foo import bar
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not python expert but I think if you really don't want to have `__init__.py` in every directory all you can do is create a `sys.path` for your `root` directory. This will allow you to import module inside root directory without `__init__.py`.

Find the `site-packages` folder (if u're using venv then it's inside `your_env/lib/python3.x/site-packages`) and inside `site-packages` folder create a `.pth` file and inside that file you can write the path to `root` directory. Example, `/Users/your_name/Desktop/root`. Now you can import like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an option without modifying `sys.path`.
You can either run via

```sh
PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) pytest
```

or

```sh
python -m pytest
```

assuming in both cases you are at the root of your project directory.