# No module name error for a module which I created

Tags: python

I got automation using Python and is set up on a VM from paperspace when I add it from my side to the VM I got an error message, no module name for a specific module from which I got the file objects, even if I try to use the PYTHONPATH no changes, the environment variables are added.
On my end the module is imported and is working
I got the following path for my object.py:
C:\Users\Public\Checkleads\T
which got the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Zoho_crm:
    sing_in  ='zgh-login'
    email = 'login_id'
    next = 'nextbtn'
    password = 'password'


    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def input_password(self,password_zoho):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.password).send_keys(password_zoho)

    def clic_next(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.next).click()

    def input_user(self,user_zoho):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.email).send_keys(user_zoho)

    def click_sign(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(self.sing_in).click()




class Boost_media:

    first_name = 'elInput'
    download_button  ='//*[@id="col-left-113"]/div'
    email_field = '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/input'
    schedule_button = '//*[@id="tmp_button-98453"]/a'
    book_button = 'elButtonSize1'
    first_name_popup= '//*[@id="Name"]'
    email_pop= '//*[@id="Email"]'
    phone = '//*[@id="phone"]'
    last_name_pop = 'Last_Name'
    submit_button = '//*[@id="zb-bi-schedule-btn"]'
    email_cold_email_page = '/html/body/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/input'
    download_button_cold = '//*[@id="tmp_button-77032"]/a'
    booK_your = '/html/body/div[1]/div[10]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a'
    specific_time_evening ='//*[@id="zb-bnc-timee0"]'
    specific_time_morning = '//*[@id="zb-bnc-timem0"]'
    specific_time_night = '//*[@id="zb-bnc-timen0"]'
    specific_field = '//*[@id="What are your top business goals in the next 12-24 months?"]'


    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
    def click_specific_time_night(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.specific_time_night).click()

    def click_specific_time_morning(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.specific_time_morning).click()

    def click_specific_time_evening(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.specific_time_evening).click()

    def click_book_your(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.booK_your).click()

    def click_download_cold(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.download_button_cold).click()
```

And my code inside the test case is:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from datetime import datetime

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains



from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os
import glob
# import cv2
# import numpy as np

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from T.objects import Boost_media,Zoho_crm

import keyword
from datetime import date
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pytz


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
class Test_Boost_0:
    baseURL = 'https://marketing.boostmediagroup.com/grab-your-free-marketing-assessment-test'
    baseURL2 = 'https://cold-email.boostmediagroup.com/index'
    baseURL3 = 'https://free-assessment.boostmediagroup.com/get-your-free-assessment-today'
    baseURL4 = 'https://grow.boostmediagroup.com/'
    baseURL5 = 'https://jbty.brizy.site/'
    baseURL6 = 'https://bookings.boostmediagroup.com/#/customer/bmgstrategysession'
    # baseURL7 =
    first_name = 'Test'
    last_name = 'Automation'
    email = 'testautomation@boostmediagroup.com'
    time_now = datetime.now()
    current_time = datetime.now()
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Bucharest')
    current_time_with_tz = tz.localize(current_time)
    formatted_time = current_time_with_tz.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
    formatted_time_0 = '{}:{}{}'.format(formatted_time[:-2], formatted_time[-2],formatted_time[0])
    first_name_pop = 'Test' + str(time_now)
    last_name_pop = '734346474'
    email_pop = 'test@bmgautomation.com'


    def test_redirects(self):
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL2)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.lp = Boost_media(self.driver)
        self.lp.click_username()
        self.lp.set_username(self.first_name)
        self.lp.set_lastname(self.last_name)
        time.sleep(2)
        # Find element by ID or some other method
        # element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/input')
        # Run JavaScript to scroll until the element is in view
        # self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        self.lp.set_email_gold(self.email)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.lp.click_download_cold()
        time.sleep(5)
        elemenet_to = self.driver.find_element_by_id('custom-thanks').is_enabled()
        if elemenet_to == True:
            assert True
        else:
            assert False

        self.driver.get(self.baseURL3)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.lp.click_book_your()
        time.sleep(5)
        elemenet_to = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('text-center')[0].is_enabled()
        if elemenet_to == True:
            assert True
        else:
            assert False
        time.sleep(30)

    # #
    # #
```

and when I run I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Public\CheckLeads\test_check_leads.py", line 45, in module
from T.objects import Boost_Media, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'T'
```

I tried to rename the module and re-added but there was no change.

Later edit:
My folder structure is:

```
root_path>
│   app.py
│   README.md   
│
└───O
│   │   init.py
│   │   objects.py
│   
│   
│          
│          
│   
└───testCases
    │   test_check_leads.py
```

And from O dir I want to import the objects.py in the testCases dir into the test_check_leads.py file and I am using

```
from O.objects import Boost_media
```

which is a class

Comment: Please, do not post any kind of text as image.

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: Can you describe your project folders and files structure? It is not clear. You probably are calling your module from the wrong folder or haven't added the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: You could check 'sys.path' if the module path is available. Additionally, you could also add a treeview of your current project. I had also some issues in the past inside my testing folder due a missing __init__.py.

Comment: @MarcelS. The init.py is in the T folder

Comment: @alec_djinn I added the structure

Comment: @GeogrianCostea i meant something like the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598408/init-py-needed-for-imports-to-work-in-pytest-but-using-python-3-8 sorry for the misleading

Comment: @MarcelS. doesn't work but thank you!

Comment: It should be `__init__.py` not `init.py`. Please check if the file is named correctly.

Comment: Try `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` in the top (before importing your library but after `import sys`) of your test files. But make sure `__init__.py` is in each module directory.

Comment: BTW, your and third-party library importing statements should place after the standard libraries. e.g., `import os` and so on --> `import selenium` --> `import your_module`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` in the top (before importing your library but after `import sys`) of your test files.

But make sure `__init__.py` is in each module directory.

Answer (score -1):

A very common practice when you're working with imports in Python ...

Let's assume the root directory of your project is `<root_path>`. So, the starting point of the application would be something like `<root_path>/app.py`. Let's also add a few directories under `<root_path>`, like this:

```
<root_path>
│   app.py
│   README.md   
│
└───dir1
│   │   script1.py
│   │   script2.py
│   │
│   └───subdir1
│       │   script3.py
│       │   file_1.txt
│   
└───dir2
    │   script4.py
```

To access

- `script1.py` in `app.py`, you would write `from dir1 import script1`.
- `script2.py` in `script1.py`, you would write `from dir1 import script2`.
- `script3.py` in `app.py`, you would write `from dir1.subdir1 import script3`.
- `script3.py` in `script4.py`, you would write `from dir1.subdir1 import script3`.

In short, consider just the hierarchy starting from the `<root_path>`, just everywhere.

And, always run your application (`app.py`) from `<root_path>`.

Comment: Same error no module found