# Why does pytest return a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import the src folder?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project named `unit_testing` with 2 subfolders named `src/` and `tests/`. In `src` there is a file called my_functions.py and in tests I have a file called test_my_functions.py.

This is the code in my_functions.py

```
def adding_pos(a, b, c):
if a < 0 or b < 0 or c < 0:
    output = f'function needs positive numbers'
else:
    output = a + b + c
return output
```

This is the code in test_my_functions.py

```
# import libs

import pytest
from src.my_functions import adding_pos


# %% test

class TestAddingPos(object):
    def test_adding(self):
        assert adding_pos(2, 5, 6) == 13

    def test_adding_neg(self):
        assert adding_pos(-1, 2, 3) == 'function needs positive numbers'
```

In the CLI, if I go to the test folder and then run pytest, I keep getting a `ModuleNotfoundError` saying the `src` module can not be found. I don' understand why because in test_my_functions.py I import functions from src.my_functions and this works.

Why does this not work?

Comment: What happens if you run `pytest` from the outermost folder, not from the tests folder? Instead of going inside tests and doing `pytest test_my_functions.py` (which I assume you are doing), how about doing `pytest tests`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named ...'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10253826/2745495)

Comment: If I go to the root director unit_testing and run from the CLI $pytest tests I still get the error:

Comment: ___________________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\Hans\Documents\Python\education\unit_testing\tests\test_my_functions.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\..\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_my_functions.py:4: in <module>
    from src.my_functions import adding_pos
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module name error for a module which I created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76661222/no-module-name-error-for-a-module-which-i-created). Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76677272/20307768)

Comment: Hi, If I add an empty init file to both src and tests and run $pytest in tests it works! however, this makes it a package. I do not want that. So is there any way around this without the init files?

Comment: I don't think so. You didn't make any package unless you did `$python -m build`or `$python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and so on. `So is there any way around this without the init files?` is another question that you need to write.